# Multi - threading click macro / click recorder

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, automation, python-multiprocessing, pyautogui

I am working on a script that will listen to keystrokes till the 'q' button is pressed, afterwards it should stop the script and print out the mouse positions that were saved in 2 seconds intervals. I can't manage the threads and I am still learning this topic. Each time I run the code nothing happens but the process is running:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import pyautogui
from multiprocessing import Process

import time

mouse_positions = []
def func1():
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    mouse_positions.append(pyautogui.position())

cordinates = []
quit_status = False
keystrokes = []
    
def on_press(key):
    if "q" in str(key) :
        print('q was pressed!')
        exit("Stopped running")
        #qprint(key)
    keystrokes.append(key)
    print(keystrokes)
        #print(keystrokes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:  # Create an instance of Listener
        listener.join()  # Join the listener thread to the main thread to keep waiting for keys
```

EDIT :
To anyone intrested, here is a click macro I built, script I built previously was more like mouse capture movement. The script below will record your mouse clicks and afterwards will replay them. Much better.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse
import time

x_pos = []
y_pos = []
both_pos = []
pressed_key  = None

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        #print ("{0} {1}".format(x,y))
        print(pressed_key)
        if pressed_key == "1":
            both_pos.append("{0}".format(x,y))
            both_pos.append("{1}".format(x,y))
            #print("test" + x_pos + y_pos)
            print (x_pos + y_pos)
        else:
            pass
        if pressed_key == 'q':
            return False

def on_press(key):
    print("To replay press 'q' , to stop recording press '1' , to record again press '1' .")
    global pressed_key
    if 'Key.esc' in str(key):
        return False
    if '1' in str(key):
        pressed_key= None if pressed_key == '1' else '1'
    if 'q' in str(key):
        print("Replaying actions")
        print(str(len(both_pos)))
        for point in range(0,len(both_pos),2):
            time.sleep(3)
            print("clicking")
            pyautogui.click(x=int(both_pos[point]),y=int(both_pos[point+1]))
        print("done...")
        return False
        


mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
mouse_listener.start()
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:  # Create an instance of Listener
    listener.join()
    #print(mouse_listener.mouse_positions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use `threading` module.
I have created class `MouseListener` which inherit from `threading.Thread` class. Everything what you want to run put into `run` method. As thread stopper I used `still_run` attribute.
When you are typing, I pass to `on_press` function pressed key and `mouse_listener`. If **q** is pressed I set `mouse_listener.still_run` to `False`, what leads to stop the mouse listener.

`mouse_positions` I moved from global scope to `MouseListener`.

```py
import threading

from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import pyautogui

import time


class MouseListener(threading.Thread):
    still_run = True
    mouse_positions = []
    def run(self):
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        while self.still_run:
            time.sleep(2)
            self.mouse_positions.append(pyautogui.position())
            print(self.mouse_positions)

coordinates = []
quit_status = False
keystrokes = []


def on_press(key, mouse_listener):
    print('kp')
    if "q" in str(key):
        print('q was pressed!')
        mouse_listener.still_run = False
        print(key)
        exit("Stopped running")
    keystrokes.append(key)
    print(keystrokes)
    print(keystrokes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mouse_listener = MouseListener()
    mouse_listener.start()
    with Listener(on_press=lambda key: on_press(key, mouse_listener)) as listener:  # Create an instance of Listener
        listener.join()
    print(mouse_listener.mouse_positions)
```

Comment: It is working ! Awesome ! 
Do you mind explaining what was wrong in my code ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the line 
on_press=lambda key: on_press(key, mouse_listener) - combines both functions as one ? 
You pass the "key" parameter into on_press as well as the mouse_listener then from within you check and change the status , to false to make it stop. 

but what happens the moment  mouse_listener.start()  is executed ? 
The inheritance from threading creates a process that relates only to the MouseListener class ? After it starts you join the "listener" with "listener.join()" to the process you started with mouse_listener.start() ?

Comment: `lambda` is anonymous function.  By default, `Listener` is expecting callable object, and pass one parameter. So `lambda` acts as wrapper around your `on_press` function. Thanks to `lambda` I was able to pass another parameter to `on_press` function.
You have defined thread class, therefore each instance of this class will run as indepedent thread.

Comment: Reason why your code was not working was `p1.join()`. According to definition: *Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.* And because you had infinite loop inside `p1` your program never get to `with Listener ...` stage, and was waiting till `p1` is terminated. This can be checked If you put `print('join complete')` after your `p1.join()` command, and you will see that there will be no output.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Can you recommend course on udemy on this topic ? 

Still having hard time understanding whats the "with",  it calls the "Listener" function and passes to the "listener" object which in turn is inherited "threading" class and that's why we are able to execute "listener.join()", after it is done it ends on its own.